# C: Usar dois gets() seguidos (nomes dos players)?

Tags: c

Estou tentando faendo um joguinho, para isso exibi um menu e depois usei o comando `switch` para acessas as opções, caso o usuário queira jogar ele seleciona 1 e será pedido a ele o nome dos player 1 e 2, para isso usei o `get`porém na hora que executo o código ele pula o player 1 e vai diretamente para o player 2, como resolvo isso? Estou usando assim:

```
printf("Nome do Player1: ");
gets(player);
printf("\n");
printf("Nome do Player2: ");
gets(pl2);
```

OBS: Declarei corretamente os vetores, e esses códigos estão dentro do `case 1` do `switch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não utilize o `get` ele não é muito seguro e da bastante problema com o `buffer`, uma boa alternativa é o `scanf`.

Exemplo:

```
printf("Nome do Player1: ");
scanf("%s", &player);
printf("\n");
printf("Nome do Player2: ");
scanf("%s", &pl2);
```

Se quiser, existe o `fgets` da uma olhada [aqui](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm).

Comment: Opa, não sabia que funcionava o scanf nesse caso, já ajudou bastante, obrigado, o fgets é um pouco complicado e não abrange esse trabalho que estou fazendo, então o jeito é usar o scanf.. Obrigado

Comment: @LeonardoVIlarinho Se resolveu seu problema, marque a resposta como a solução, boa noite! :)

Comment: marquei aí já..

Answer (score 1):

Eu seria ainda mais reticente quanto ao uso indiscriminado do `scanf`. Em especial, este mesmo `scanf("%s",&p)` pode ser alvo de *buffer overflow*. Seria importante limitar o tamanho da string recebida: `scanf("%100s",&p)`.

(A bem da verdade, sou ainda mais cabreiro acerca de `scanf`; prefiro criar versões próprias usando `getc` e `putc`.)